# calculating typing speed in characters per millisecond

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Im trying to calculate the typing speed in characters per millisecond as the user types. I have two controls, richtextbox and textbox as typing area, as the user types in the text area, the speed between the characters is showed in the richtextbox.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim swatch As New Stopwatch

Dim finalSpeed As Double
Dim temp As Double


Private Sub typingArea_KeyPressed(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles typingArea.KeyPress
    swatch.Start()

    If swatch.IsRunning Then
        temp += swatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
    End If



    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Return) Then
        e.KeyChar = Nothing

        swatch.Reset()

        MsgBox(finalSpeed / typingArea.Text.Length)

        typingArea.Text = Nothing
        logArea.Text = Nothing

    End If

    If typingArea.Text <> Nothing Then
        swatch.Start()

    End If


    If swatch.IsRunning = False Then swatch.Start()

    If typingArea.Text.Length > 0 Then

        logArea.AppendText("time between two chars is " + temp.ToString() + Environment.NewLine)
        finalSpeed += temp
        temp = 0
        swatch.Restart()
        'End If
    Else
        swatch.Reset()
    End If

End Sub

Public Function returnAverageSpeed(ByVal length As Integer, ByVal total As Double) As Double
    Return total / length
End Function

End Class
```

If there is only one character in the textbox, then there is no need to calculate the speed but if the user types a second character and subsequent characters, then we begin calculating the speed. if the user presses enter, the average speed us calculated the the process is stopped until the user begins typing again in the textbox. The problem here is, the program is failing to record the speed between the first and the second character but the others seem to be working fine for now.

Comment: Do you realize that just the fact that you update your label with your calculus at every char typed invalidates the correctness of your measure?

Comment: FWIW - The worlds fastest typist typed 216 words per minute.  The average word is 5 characters plus one for separator.  That means that the characters per millisecond is less than a whole character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, the code was a bit hard to read. And I'm not sure why the first gap between two keypresses didnt work. But having rewritten it a bit, it seems to work.

```
Private Sub typingArea_KeyPressed(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles typingArea.KeyPress
    'if the stopwatch is running add elapsed time. Otherwise start the stopwatch
    If swatch.IsRunning Then
        temp = swatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
        finalSpeed += temp
    Else
        swatch.Start()
    End If
    'if user presses return, pop up the message box, reset the swatch, clear the boxes  and exit the sub
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Return) Then
        e.KeyChar = Nothing
        swatch.Reset()
        MsgBox(finalSpeed / typingArea.Text.Length)
        typingArea.Text = Nothing
        logArea.Text = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf typingArea.TextLength > 0 Then
        'If the user has pressed anything other than return and there is already text in the typing area then do this
        logArea.AppendText("time between two chars is " + temp.ToString() + Environment.NewLine)
        finalSpeed += temp
        temp = 0
        swatch.Restart()
    ElseIf typingArea.TextLength = 0 Then
        'if there is nothing in the typing area then reset swatch
        swatch.Restart()
    End If

End Sub
```